# How to remove parent slug from child posts

Tags: wordpress

I need a way to ignore the parent slug from the child posts. But without using any plugin.

```
Coming: http://test.com/test-parent/test-child
Desired: http://test.com/test-child
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need the rewrite module of Apache: `mod_rewrite`.

Then do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^test-parent/(.*)$ $1
```

Here is the official documentation of mod_rewrite: [click](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: I am not bound with specific parent slug. It could be anything instead of `test-parent`.